# MouseHook causes juddering mouse movement when processing

Tags: c#

I am building an application using UIAutomation which labels certain widgets on a typical Microsoft Windows user interface, e.g. Windows Explorer, control panel. I am using appropriate threading with UIA based on a Microsoft blog example and everything is working well. The labelling of the widgets is triggered by certain events and one of these events is a mouse click using a low level mousehook code shown below. The problem I have is that when the UI is updated on a mouseclick the mouse movement becomes juddery (as in not smooth) while the UI is updating. So what springs to mind is that the mouse action event needs to run in a different thread. Although I have been programming for quite a few years it has been off and on so I am far from confident when it comes to such threading issues. I have tried the code below in the mouse auction event but it makes no difference. Any help greatly appreciated. I would particularly appreciate example code with an explanation in particular.

```
// Setup global mouse hook to react to mouse clicks under certain conditions, see event handler
                MouseHook.Start();
                MouseHook.MouseAction += new EventHandler(MouseHook_MouseAction);

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace myapplication
{
    public static class MouseHook
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
          LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
          IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        public static event EventHandler MouseAction = delegate { };

        private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

        private enum MouseMessages
        {
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
          //  WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
          //  WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
            WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
            //WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public POINT pt;
            public uint mouseData;
            public uint flags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        public static void Start()
        {
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);

        }
        public static void stop()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
        }

        private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
        private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

        private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                IntPtr hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle("user32"), 0);
                if (hook == IntPtr.Zero) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
                return hook;
            }
        }

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private static IntPtr HookCallback(
          int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && (MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam || MouseMessages.WM_RBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam ||
                MouseMessages.WM_MOUSEWHEEL == (MouseMessages)wParam))
            {
                MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
                MouseAction(null, new EventArgs());
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

    }
}

private void MouseHook_MouseAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           //my attempt at threading solution
                Thread th = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    UpdateUI();
                    Application.Run();
                });
                th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

                th.Start();
}
```

Comment: so on each mouse move you update a UI and rerun the whole app? why?

Comment: Try using `this.BeginInvoke()` inside the handler for `MouseHook_MouseAction()` to call a method in the UI context.

Comment: Not on each mouse move but on each mouseclick (left or right) because that is the nature of the application and it is not returning the whole app but simply updating the existing UI.

Comment: I tried currentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((del)delegate () {UpdateUI ()}); as the main UI is not a window or Windows control but same problem thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Probably not the right place to ask this question but if I am looking for a contractor for some consultancy regarding this application how do I do that. Just advertise on the forum presumably?

Comment: Sorry I should rephrase that regarding my comment calling begininvoke. The calling class for the mousehook is not a window or a Windows control but the calling class instance/controller for the application calls some WPF elements which forms the UI for the application.

Comment: Use Debug > Windows > Threads to see how many threads are running when it gets "juddery".  Ought to be scary.